# Real time timer count down in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Please i need an idea or a solution on how to develop a realtime timer count down in laravel. I will allocated a certain time in the database, then the timer would count down to the allocated time in the database and also update the database every seconds or minutes with the latest countdown. More also perform a task if the countdown elapses. Thanks

Comment: You have to store the time when the countdown finishes, not how much time has left. This is because your app runs every time it is requested, which means unspecified intervals.

Comment: try countdown js plugin

Comment: In a situation where the user logout from the system. I want to be able to keep track of the last count down and then update the database.

Comment: Thats not so easy. You dont know when user loged out always. What if user close the browser, but dont log out?

Comment: @Autista_z in that case it can be tracked with `window.onbeforeupload` event. And handle it with an AJAX request that will do necessary work

Comment: @lura Varzari I was thinking on using setInterval. Any time there is a count down, then i can use ajax to update my record on the database.